# Javascript, find first empty spot in grid

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a grid with items inside of it with x and y co-orditantes. I am trying to write a function (with lodash) to determine where is the first empty spot where the top most left most spot is the first position.

I am trying to do this by iterating over each spot until I find the first empty spot. It is only a 2 column layout so I work through them in a pattern like so - x: 0, y:0 -> x:1, y:0 -> x:0, y:1 -> x:1, y:1 ... and then checking all the items along the way to see if there is *not* a match, so I then know if there is an opening. My attempt looks like so :

```
  function fillEmptySpace(isFilled, startX, startY) {
  if (!isFilled) {
    _.forEach(items, function(item, i) {
      if (!_.isMatch(item, {
          'x': startX
        }) && !_.isMatch(item, {
          'y': startY
        })
        ) {
        console.log("empty spot at", startX, startY);
        isFilled = true;
      } else if (!_.isMatch(item, {
          'x': startX + 1
        }) && !_.isMatch(item, {
          'y': startY
        })) {
        console.log("empty spot at", startX + 1, startY);
        isFilled = true;
      }
    });

    startY += 1;
    fillEmptySpace(isFilled, startX, startY);
  }
}

fillEmptySpace(false, 0, 0);
```

The data looks like so :

```
  var items = [{
  i: 'a',
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  w: 1,
  h: 1,
  maxW: 2
}, {
  i: 'b',
  x: 1,
  y: 4,
  w: 1,
  h: 1,
  maxW: 2
}, {
  i: 'c',
  x: 0,
  y: 1,
  w: 1,
  h: 1,
  maxW: 2
}, {
  i: 'd',
  x: 0,
  y: 2,
  w: 1,
  h: 1,
  maxW: 2
}];
```

And here is the fiddle I have been fooling around in : https://jsfiddle.net/alexjm/ugpy13xd/38/

I can't seem to get this logic quite right, I am not sure a this point where I am getting it wrong. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Just as a note : with the provided data it should identify the first empty space as x:1, y:0, however right now it is saying empty spot at 0 0, which cannot be correct. Thanks!

Comment: What is your grid size ?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH it's 2 columns and unlimited rows - right now its probably 6 rows at most but it can expand.

Comment: Downvoter care to tell me how I can improve this question or what I am asking incorrectly?

Comment: Is always `h` and `w` equal to 1 ?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH no all the properties on those items can change, that's why I was trying to use isMatch to just look at the x and y and make a comparison

Comment: Here is my solution, it's more efficient ! My idea was to establish a map for the grid then fill it with the data and then you can easily spot all spaces ! https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/5akgnnkf/

Comment: If you like it I can add it as an answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to 2D arrays, the 1D index can be calculated with `x + y * width`. If we then sort the 1D indexes, we can create an O(nlogn) solution:

```
function findEmptySpace(grid, width) {
  var index = _(grid)
    .map(function(p) { return p.x + p.y * width })
    .sortBy()
    .findIndex(_.negate(_.eq));
  if (index < 0) index = grid.length;
  return {
    x: index % width,
    y: index / width >> 0 // ">> 0" has the same result as "Math.floor"
  };
}
```

```js
var items = [{x:0,y:0},{x:0,y:4},{x:0,y:1},{x:0,y:2}];

function findEmptySpace(grid, width) {
  var index = _(grid)
    .map(function(p) { return p.x + p.y * width; })
    .sortBy()
    .findIndex(_.negate(_.eq));
  if (index < 0) index = grid.length;
  return {
    x: index % width,
    y: index / width >> 0 // ">> 0" has the same result as "Math.floor"
  };
}

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  var space = findEmptySpace(items, 2);
  items.push(space);
  console.log(space);
};
```

```css
#btn { font-size: 14pt }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Fill the Empty Space</button>
```

If you pre-sort the array, the solution would be worst-case O(n).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Current implementation eventual persists at "finding" only `{x: 0, y: 1}` which is already present in the original datset; the grid should be infinite in rows so it should never get stuck. Further, changing the test data's last item y to `20` it borks even earlier, on the fourth attempt, stuck on returning `{x: 1, y: 2}`

Comment: @rgthree Nice catch! That was a sneaky bug. Apparently `.sort()` Isn't actually a part of lodash, so it was doing weird casting with strings. Fixed now with `.sortBy()`

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest checking to see if the point exists vs checking to see if it doesn't. Iterate over each item in the list to see if it exists if it does set a flag, then increment positions through your grid. Keep in mind this will not account for coords less than your intial value of "startY". Consider the following code:

```
 function findEmptySpace(startX, startY) {
   var isFilled = false;
    _.forEach(items, function(item, i) {
      if (_.isMatch(item, { 'x': startX }) && _.isMatch(item, { 'y': startY }) {
        // this spot is filled check next x
        isFilled = true;
        continue;
    }
  }

  if (isFilled == true) {
    // we need to recursively call our function but I don't know the value of x
    (startX == 0) ? findEmptySpace(1, startY): findEmptySpace(0, startY + 1);
  } else {
    console.log("Congrats, we found a spot", startX, startY);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're always going to find a match at `0,0` since your logic is finding if there is *any item in the list that is not on 0,0*, instead of if there *is an item in the list on 0,0*

What you really want to do is stop checking once you've found an item in the current `x,y` (and, additionally, check **both** `x` and `y` in your `isMatch`). You can use your existing routine and your existing `isFilled` check:

```
function fillEmptySpace(isFilled, startX, startY) {
  _.forEach(items, function(item, i) {
    if (!isFilled) {
      if (!_.isMatch(item, {'x': startX, 'y': startY})) {
        console.log("empty spot at", startX, startY);
        isFilled = true;
      } else if (!_.isMatch(item, {'x': startX + 1, 'y': startY})) {
        console.log("empty spot at", startX + 1, startY);
        isFilled = true;
      }
    }
  });

  if (!isFilled) {
    startY += 1;
    fillEmptySpace(isFilled, startX, startY);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why someone would down vote w/o a comment; that's just poor SO etiquette. Further, not only does my answer provide minimal changes to the OPs routine, but the later suggestions take into account a width and height for each item (assuming OP means these by their original `w` and `h` values) which none of the other answers do.

Comment: Hmm, it could just be that you fixed their code without speeding it up. This is still an O(n^2) implementation since it has to look at all of the objects for each index. Otherwise, it expounds mostly on parts of the question that the OP didn't need help with.

Comment: @4castle To be fair, OP only asked how to fix his own logic to get the desired output, not how to speed up his routine, which is precisely how I answered it "above the fold." While I love your optimization and do think it deserves to be the approved answer, both your speed refactor and my _second part_ to incorporate an item width/height, go beyond what the OP asked for. Since my answer is not incorrect, and does go above and beyond, a down vote is quite unwarranted; especially w/o a comment.

Comment: @rgthree I think your first statement is very inaccurate, "it looks like the logic is finding out if any item is not on 0,0 which, of course, you'll always have a block not on 0,0 ". The first item in the list is located on 0,0 this means there is always a block on 0,0. The real problem is the OP is checking to see if the x,y they passed in match each item in the items list and is returning the first item in the list that is not a match which is 0,0.  With that being said I don't think that any working solution should get a down vote, better to receive constructive criticism in the comments.

Comment: @dspano I did mean what I said in its original form, but perhaps the wording could be better. The original phrase meant "you'll always have a block *[in the list]* not on 0,0" not that there will be no blocks on 0,0. (Of course that's not necessarily true with a different dataset that contains only one block that is on 0,0, but that's outside the provided dataset.). I'll reword the beginning to better explain the scenario. Thanks!